# Looping through an array, index error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, nsarray, nsrangeexception

I am creating a `UIScrollView` that scrolls sideways and has a number of buttons and labels (that go with the buttons) that I am adding programmatically.

I have 44 buttons and labels, so I want to create them through an array.

This is how I am trying to do it (I'm a newish programmer so I know for a fact its the wrong way to do it.

Keep in mind, `nameArray` holds strings for the labels and the `picArray` holds strings for the filenames for pictures.

Anyways, this is in my `viewDidLoad:`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 44; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [nameArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [self makeLabelsAndButtons:path];
    //NSLog(@"index path is:%@", path);
}
```

The method that this for loop is referencing is written below:

```
-(void)makeLabelsAndButtons:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
NSString *nameString = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath];
NSString *picString = [picArray objectAtIndex:indexPath];

NSLog(@"name: %@, pic:%@", nameString, picString);

}
```

There is not much in the `makeLabelsAndButtons` method because I am trying to get the concept down before adding the meat of the code.

This is the error I crash with:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 54564 beyond bounds [0 .. 43]
```

I know that this means the array is out of the bounds but I have no idea why.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nameArray holds strings for the labels, then path is not an NSIndexPath, it's a string. So you're passing a string to objectAtIndex: which, of course wants an integer not a string.

Even if it were an NSIndexPath, your code would still be wrong because you want an integer not an index path to pass to objectAtIndex.

I think what you want to do is just pass i to your makeLabelsAndButtons method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 44; i++) {
    [self makeLabelsAndButtons:i];
    //NSLog(@"index path is:%@", path);
}

-(void)makeLabelsAndButtons:(NSInteger)index{
    NSString *nameString = [nameArray objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *picString = [picArray objectAtIndex:index];

    NSLog(@"name: %@, pic:%@", nameString, picString);
}
```

Comment: I tried using i just like that because that was my first instinct as well, but i get the error, "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSIndexPath *' is disallowed with ARC"   Can I not do this when I have ARC on?

Comment: @tyler53, yeah, but you shouldn't be using NSIndexPath, just NSInteger. Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

either this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < [nameArray count]; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [nameArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [self makeLabelsAndButtons:path];

}
```

or like this...

```
for (NSIndexPath *path in nameArray) {
    [self makeLabelsAndButtons:path];

}
```

Comment: both your answer and the one below helped, thanks alot guys :)